# "This app isn't verified" warning on the Google oauth screen while app is verified

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

We are using Youtube API to perform Oauth to our application. One of the scopes requested is `force-ssl`, which is a sensitive scope, so we had to go through the verification procedure. Now the settings screen in the development console show that the application is verified (verification status - Published) and the `force-ssl` scope has the green tick, as well as our authorized domains (please see screenshots). Nevertheless, users are getting the "This app isn't verified" warning, which is undesirable. What can be the reason for this warning and how can we get rid of that?
[image: Oauth consent screen settings]
[image: Scope settings screen]
[image: User warning]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was the UPLOAD scope, that was requested as well.
For some reason, it was not present in the scope list, so I did not pay attention to it, not speaking of verifying it with the support. I removed it and now ew have no warning screen. Posting this in case someone runs into the same problem.
P.S. to verify the UPLOAD scope you will have to provide the proof of using it in an appropriate way, we have the implementation of publishing functionality in plans, but not in the current feature set. In our case, it was impossible to get the UPLOAD scope verified.